# How is the honey spoiling honey question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

The question **[Why doesn't honey spoil quickly?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/why-doesnt-honey-spoil-quickly)** was closed as a duplicate of **[Sugar as a defense against bacteria?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/sugar-as-a-defence-against-bacteria)**. These questions are similar but really not duplicates. See my comment:

> One reason is that sugar has a pH of 7, while honey has a pH of 3.26 to 4.48, a killing field for bacteria. Also, bees process honey by means of an enzyme called glucose oxidase, AKA 'Penicillin A' (formerly) or 'Notatin', which reduces atmospheric O2 to H2O2 (Hydrogen peroxide), forming an antimicrobial barrier on the honey surface. Also, bacteria become desiccated in honey because of the hygroscopic effects of the sugar (mostly supersaturated in honey). Basically, related, but not a duplicate question.

Why is this question remaining closed?

Comment: I totally agree with you. It's related but not a duplicate.

Comment: Something that should also be kept in mind is that duplicates or closely related questions using *different search terms* should be answered simply to make the result of a search query more likely to contain an answer.  Not everyone would immediately substitute 'sugar' for 'honey' in a search for that question, *especially if they don't know that the answer is based on sugar already*, i.e. they are looking for the answer and don't already know it.